# Set up Ubuntu server to intercept traffic directed at another IP and send it to Apache?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, routing, man-in-the-middle, promiscuous

I'm trying to reverse-engineer the protocol used by HP ePrint. For some reason the printer responds with an error when I override the DNS to point to my own local server, so I decided to create a static routing entry on the router to send traffic headed for the ePrint IP (15.240.60.112) through my server (192.168.1.13). Of course, my server doesn't know what to do with traffic intended for that IP, so (I'm assuming) it drops the packets. What I want to do is have Apache respond to those packets as if they were intended for 192.168.1.13 using a self-signed SSL certificate, which the printer hopefully won't treat differently. How can I set this up?

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? If there's something wrong with this question, please let me know--just downvoting me doesn't give me the opportunity to learn from my mistakes!

Comment: Mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".  Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out on my own.

All I did was `ifconfig eth0 add 15.240.60.112` on the server to tell it to respond on that IP as well. My virtual host is set to respond on *:443, so it will respond on any IP it gets packets addressed to.